# Android Studio detects device only after running it the second time

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have Android Studio 2.3.2 installed on my Windows 10. These are the steps I have to undergo to get my code working.

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Android Monitor doesn't detect any device.
3. I type `adb start-server` in the Terminal.
4. Close Android Studio.
5. Reopen Android Studio
6. Now the Android Monitor initializes and detects my device.

Now, I don't want to go through the first 4 steps. What should I do?

P.S I have tried running the `adb start-server` from command prompt before doing the first step, but that changes nothing.

Comment: Which device (phone/brand) you're using? Have you tried with other devices or Emulator?

Comment: @Shashanth it is Yu Yunique. No, I haven't tried Emulator because my firmware doesn't support it. By the way, as I said it works when I type adb start-server in the terminal